# Triggering dynamically generated text file for download

Tags: php, file, download

I am currently trying to implement a PHP page that will generate a code when a user clicks a button. The code will be generated on the fly, and then the PHP page will trigger a download file that will prompt the user to save the text file on their machine.

After reading numerous posts, I am using this bit of code which is short, concise and does exactly what I need:

```
{
$result = "Your code is: " . $_POST['req_code'];
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=code.lic');
header('Content-type: text/plain');
echo $result . "\n";
}
```

However, the downloaded file does not only contain the code, it also contains all the HTML from the current page. Below is just a fraction of what is included in the file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-CA">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>My Account | ...
```

I have tried using the "exit();" function to terminate the stream but it still outputs all the HTML.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here? The file should only contain the contents of $result.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Although this is an old thread, there are search results that still direct to here. So to answer the original question (sort of) by giving a simple stand-alone example that works, here goes:
Create two files, 'index.php' and 'redirect.php'

index.php:

```
<?php
$head = <<<EOHEAD
<head>
    <title>Download document test</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="txt/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
EOHEAD;
$body = <<<EOBODY
<body>
    <form action="redirect.php" method="post" id="mainform">
        <input type="submit" name="download" value="Download"/>
        <input type="submit" name="cancel" value="Cancel"/>
    </form>
</body>
EOBODY;
echo $head.$body;
?>
```

redirect.php:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['download'])) {
        header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=test.txt');
        header('Content-type: text/plain');
        echo "Hello World\n";
    }
    else {
        header("location:index.php");
    }
?>
```

Comment: If I owned the question. I would accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to either a) Make a new page to download the file (without **any** HTML) or b) Remove **all** HTML from the current page. Also, you are not supposed to send any content before calling `header()`:

> Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is
>   sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: Well, I followed your suggestion an placed the $result, headers and echo in a new file called license.php. Then I call that file using require_once('license.php') but it still includes HTML content.

Comment: @Rich95 You need to send the user to license.php, not include it.

Comment: Ok, let me try this again. Would I use the redirect function to send a user to that page? I though the redirect also had to go at the top of the page which would make its use in a if-then statement difficult?

Comment: @Rich95 you could use a meta redirect or a javascript redirect.

Comment: I'm surprised this is so complicated, and that you can't do it all with PHP. I would think creating a file, adding some text to it, saving it and triggering download would not be so tricky... Then again, it's probably my beginner skills. ;) Anyway, I still can't get this to work.

Comment: @Rich95 You **can** do it all with PHP, but I need to see your entire file before I can help you with that.

Comment: Is it ok if I post the PHP contents here for you to see? It's the order_details.php page of WooCommerce.

Comment: @Rich95 Post it on pastebin.com and link to it here

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to delete all HTML code from download site, but there cannot be ANY HTML code before function, that downloads your files. Put your code ad the top of the page and it should be fine

Comment: Could anyone supply a pseudo code example so I understand this better? I don't know how to put the code at the top of the page if there are if-then statements around it.

Comment: You do need to delete all HTML code, because otherwise the html after the code will still be downloaded.